# How to remove the object in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I decided to start with a simple chat. Actually there was a problem.
So, I have an object ChatServer, which implements the object is created socket.io, and work with connecting and disconnecting clients.

```
"use strict";

var SocketServer = require('socket.io')
    , Client = require('./Client.js');

class ChatServer {
    constructor(app, http) {
        var io = SocketServer(http)
            , clients = {};

        io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            console.log('Client ' + socket.id + ' connected');

            clients[socket.id] = new Client(app, socket);

            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log('Client ' + socket.id + ' disconnected');

                clients[socket.id] = undefined;
                delete clients[socket.id];
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = ChatServer;
```

When connecting the client object is created Client, which implements processing of messages, for this particular client.

```
"use strict";

class Client {
    constructor(app, socket) {
        this.app = app;
        this.socket = socket;

        this.app.on('chat.sendMessage', this.sendMessage.bind(this));
    }

    sendMessage(message) {
        console.log('Client ' + this.socket.id + ' on chat.sendMessage');
        this.socket.emit('chat.sendMessage', message);
    }
}

module.exports = Client;
```

app - it EventEmitter, from which come periodically posts 'chat.sendMessage' (for testing), in client objects, messages are received and sent to the browser.

However, if the client disconnected, client object is not going away, and continues to catch the messages and send to a disconnected socket.

```
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA connected
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA disconnected
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
Client ZbEFj8ykXba9CxLiAAAA on chat.sendMessage
```

I probably do not fully understand the mechanics of destroing objects, I know that it needs to remove all references to it, that here and done.

```
clients[socket.id] = undefined;
delete clients[socket.id];
```

However, this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to assign undefined to array element, it will be undefined once you delete like

```
delete clients[socket.id];
```

actually when you use var keyword it attach variable current scope called  "VariableEnvironment"

try to **avoid var keyword** in this particular case.

for more information http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/